# Корень в слове ПИСЬМО

Tags: словообразование

Выполнить морфемный разбор слова ПИСЬМО не так просто, как кажется на первый взгляд. Что такое М в данном слове? Это часть корня? Суффикс? Или второй корень (в одном из словарей видела и такую версию)?

Comment: А в каких словарях "м" рассматривается как часть корня или как второй корень? Во мне известных словарях -- суффикс.

Comment: http://slovonline.ru/slovar_sostav/b-16/id-428357/pismo.html

Comment: Да чушь это, а не разбор! **Екатерина**, Вы по своей ссылке, возможно, не прочитали это: _Онлайн разбор слова по составу (морфемный разбор) Письмо **произведен программными средствами, поэтому может содержать ошибки**.
Если Вы нашли ошибку или морфемный разбор слова Письмо произведен неверно (правильность указания корня, приставки, суффикса, основы слова), пожалуйста сообщите об этом в комментариях к разбору, мы постараемся учесть Ваши замечания._

Comment: Да нет, прочитала, конечно. И задумалась о том, нужен ли такой словарь в принципе. А вот ещё сегодня слово ВЕДЬМА  вспомнилось. В нём тоже М.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Как разобрать по составу слово "письмо"? | Большой вопрос .ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/711292-kak-razobrat-po-sostavu-slovo-pismo.html)

**Итак, пись/м/о, М — суффикс.** А откуда он взялся — это никого не волнует, хотя нет в русском языке такого суффикса (в словаре словообразовательных единиц не указан).

В этимологическом словаре написано следующее: письмо — 10-11 вв, от общеславянского "пись" от писать.

Но вот интересная информация: **писомый** (последнее — устаревшая форма, но в ироническом штиле иногда используемая). Сравнить: искать — **искомый.**

Пример иронического письма: В основном **писомое** «экспертом» представляет собой феерический бред.

Так что не исключено, что **М — это часть суффикса страдательного причастия.**

**Дополнение**

Итак,  писать — письмо, белить (белый) — бельмо, драть — дерьмо, сравнить:  искомый, весомый, ведомый.

В этих словах **сходная схема образования по типу**: рвать (действие)  — рваный (признак как результат действия) — рваньё (предмет, обладающий данным признаком). Это так называемые  "субстантиваты страдательных причастий.

Поэтому при разборе слова пись/м/о  желательное указать, что **суффикс М - это нерегулярный и непродуктивный суффикс**, который не используется для образования новых слов, но встречается в небольшом количестве ранее образованных существительных.

Answer (score 4):

В школьном грамматическом словаре всё-таки пись/м/о, у Потихи и Текучёва тоже, но в некоторых новых пособиях разбирается и как письм/о.

Это мнение сторонников формальной школы, которые утверждают, что в современном языке нет суффикса -м-, да и *письмо* сейчас не всегда соотносится со словом "писать" - его и печатают, и набирают, значит, *писать* и *письмо* уже не однокоренные, они только исторически родственные.

Функционально-семантическая школа утверждает, что исторический смысл остался понятен: письмо - результат действия писать, а то, что оно изменило вид, неважно. Сущ."письмо" образовано ещё в древности от глагола *писати* с помощью суффикса -ьм- (как бельмо от "белый") со значением "писание" и "написанный текст", и нет причин отрицать существование суффикса, который стал нерегулярен. В школе придерживаются этого взгляда, но в отдельных пособиях по новым программам в младших классах есть и письм/о. В онлайн-словарях оба варианта.

Других мнений (что два корня) не слышала.

Так что объяснить можно оба варианта, а как разбирать - это зависит от цели разбора: если для школы, нужно знать, какой версии придерживается автор учебника.

Comment: _Людмила: ...но в некоторых новых пособиях разбирается и как письм/о._ === Людмила, не подскажете, в каких именно?

Comment: *письмо сейчас не всегда соотносится со словом "писать"* — странная точка зрения. "Писать" — значит "изображать графические знаки", а делается это посредством авторучки или электронных устройств, отношения к делу не имеет. Такое ощущение, что цель "отдельных пособий" разорвать связи между словами в головах у детей.

Comment: Слава, а помните начало перестройки и множество альтернативных программ? Одна моя приятельница работала в начальной школе и показала новый учебник. Меня там многое удивило, письм/о тоже было, я ещё возмущалась. А она сказала:" А дети понимают". Я говорю, что они просто твоему авторитету верят и книге.

Comment: Да бог с ней, с началом перестройки! Сейчас-то в каких-либо  альтернативных программах или словарях существует  разбор, отличный от общепринятого, или же нет? Повторюсь: я с таким разбором не встречался. Ну а то, что встречается в безыменных онлайн-словарях... Я стараюсь такими словарями не пользоваться и ссылок на них в своих сообщениях не давать.

Comment: Интересно, а  Aer утверждает, что суффикса ьм не существует, в чем я сильно сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 4):

Давно, в незапамятные времена, к основе праславянского глагола **pisati* (писать) присоединился суффикс *-ьm(o)* (-ьм(о)), получилось *письмо*. Сейчас так слова не образуются, *словообразовательная модель* стала непродуктивной, поэтому в современном русском языке возникают проблемы с морфемным анализом слова. Единственно верного решения нет, т. к. а) мы можем выделить корень *письм*, но тогда это будет значить, что утратилась связь с глаголом *писать*, б) возникают затруднения с выделением суффикса *м*, который не используется при образовании других слов. **То есть существует два варианта: *пись/м/о* и *письм/о*.**

Answer (score 1):

> Выполнить морфемный разбор слова ПИСЬМО не так просто, как кажется на
>   первый взгляд...

А по-моему, очень просто. Во всяком случае, очень просто выделить у этого слова окончание (ср. *письм-**о**, письм-**а**, письм-**у***…) и корень: ***пись***-мо, **пис**-ать, **пис**-ание, **пис**-атель, **пис**-арь…

> Что такое М в данном слове? Это часть корня? Суффикс? Или второй
>   корень (в одном из словарей видела и такую версию)?

Что же до того, чем назвать "м"… А чем его ещё можно назвать, если не суффиксом? С таким же суффиксом, как в слове ***письмо***, были образованы когда-то  слова ***бельмо, ведьма, дерьмо…*** И если в последних двух словах мало какой словарь выделяет сейчас "м" как отдельную морфему, то в словах ***письмо*** и ***бельмо*** абсолютно все из известных мне печатных словарей квалифицируют "м" как суффикс.

Ну а что касается безымённых онлайн-словарей в Сети… Лучше, на мой взгляд, ими как можно меньше пользоваться.

===

Посмотрел по наводке  **Aer** словарь *Т. Л. Федоровой ("Разбор слова по составу. Словарь")*. У неё действительно в слове ***письмо*** выделен корень ***письм.***

Что могу сказать? Какого-то глубокого смысла в таком разборе я бы не искал: слишком много в словарях Фёдоровой ляпов.

Заехал сегодня в "Дом книги", посмотрел её словообразовательный словарь *(Фёдорова Т.Л., Щеглова О.А. "Словообразовательный словарь русского языка", М., 2016)*.  Один из примеров:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь может понять, почему в глаголе ***барабанить*** Фёдорова выделяет корень ***бараба*** и суффикс ***н***? Почему в слове ***барабанщик*** нет суффикса?..

Думаю, что и морфемный разбор слова ***письмо*** у Фёдоровой отличается от общепринятого по тем же самым причинам.

Comment: Во-первых, я не согласен, что очень просто выполнить морфемный разбор - иначе не было бы вопроса. Хорошо, что можно выделить окончание. А вот дальше трудности, как раз завязанные на *м*.  Во-вторых, *м* можно назвать частью корня, к примеру (см. "Разбор слова по составу. Словарь". Т. Л. Федорова. М., ООО "Стандарт", 2015). В-третьих, *ведьма* было образовано добавлением суф. *-ьма* к корню гл. *ве̌де̌ти*, а в образовании *бельмо*, *дерьмо* участвовал суф. *-мо*.

Comment: @Aer . Во-первых, вопрос и сложности у автора вопроса возникли только потому, что он использовал сайты, которые сами не были уверены в своей правоте. См.: _Онлайн разбор слова по составу (морфемный разбор) Письмо **произведен программными средствами, поэтому может содержать ошибки**_.  Ссылок на более-менее приличные издания, содержащие морфемный разбор, противоречащий общепринятому,  автор вопроса не дал. // Во-вторых, со словарём Фёдоровой я пока не был знаком, потому и не испытывал бы трудностей при определении того, чем является "м" в слове "письмо".

Comment: Кстати, вопрос: а какие слова Фёдорова считает однокоренными со словом "письмо"? // Ну а в-третьих: почему Вы  в слове "дерьмо" выделяете суффикс "-мо" (без "ь"), а в слове "ведьма" -- "-ьма"  (с "ь")?

Comment: Этот словарь негнездовой. Его трудно назвать авторитетным, однако он есть. Нужно добавить ерь, *-ьмо*, прошу прощения.

Comment: обратите внимание на пары: письменно-письмена, и пИсьмо (письменно) - письма.